# How can I chamge the Y values off a base chart in Altair?

Tags: altair

So working on displaying chart based on state data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

URL = 'https://covidtracking.com/api/states/daily'
# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
r = requests.get(url = URL) 

# extracting data in json format 
data = r.json() 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

state_box = alt.binding_select(options=list(df['state'].unique()))
selection = alt.selection_single(name='Data for', fields=['state'], bind=state_box)

chart1 = alt.Chart(df, title='Deaths').mark_bar().encode(
    x='dateChecked:T',
    y='death',
    tooltip=list(df.columns)
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
).interactive()
chart2 = alt.Chart(df, title='Tests').mark_bar().encode(
    x='dateChecked:T',
    y='totalTestResults',
    tooltip=list(df.columns)
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
).interactive()

(chart1 | chart2)
```

And I am using repeating code.  How can reuse the defintion for chart1 and simply change the y value, so in pseudocode:

```
chart2 = chart1.set_y('totalTestResults')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Altair's chart methods return a modified copy of the original chart. This means that you can always do something like this:

```
chart1 = alt.Chart(data).mark_point().encode(
  x='x:Q',
  y='y1:Q',
)

chart2 = chart1.encode(y='y2:Q')

chart1 | chart2
```

In this case `chart2` will have all the same properties as `chart1`, except for the updated y encoding, and `chart1` will be unmodified by the new encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out.  So first I set my "base" graph with all common parameters:

```
base = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='dateChecked:T',
    tooltip=list(df.columns)
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
).interactive()
```

Then add encodings and properties I need to change:

```
chart1 = base.encode(y='hospitalizedIncrease').properties(title='hospitalizedIncrease')
chart2 = base.encode(y='death:Q').properties(title='Deaths')
```

Then diplay :)

```
(chart1 | chart2)
```

Also figured out how to initialize my selection, by adding init to selection_single::

```
state_box = alt.binding_select(options=list(df['state'].unique()))
selection = alt.selection_single(name='Data for', fields=['state'], bind=state_box, init={'state': 'NY'})
```